# Operator[] C++ Get/Set

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble with telling the difference between get and set for the operator[]. I need to tell the difference between these function calls.

```
cout << data[5];
data[5] = 1;
```

I googled it, and the answers I found still didn't help. People suggested making the signatures for the methods different by adding const. I did that, and they still both called the same method.

There are the signatures I had used:

```
const T& operator[](unsigned int index) const;
T& operator[](unsigned int index);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to look up *proxy objects*, which are often used to distinguish reads from writes.

Comment: See Item 30 "Proxy Classes" from [More Effective C++ by Scott Meyers](http://www.amazon.com/More-Effective-Improve-Programs-ebook/dp/B004VSMDNY/ref=la_B004BBEYYW_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1381129998&sr=1-2) for an extensive discussion on this subject, including surprising pitfalls (related to user-defined conversions) that proxy classes can give you. That material is [mandatory reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The solution is to use a "proxy" object that will delay the actual operation:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct MyArray {
    std::vector<T> data;
    MyArray(int size) : data(size) {}

    struct Deref {
        MyArray& a;
        int index;
        Deref(MyArray& a, int index) : a(a), index(index) {}

        operator T() {
            std::cout << "reading\n"; return a.data[index];
        }

        T& operator=(const T& other) {
            std::cout << "writing\n"; return a.data[index] = other;
        }
   };

   Deref operator[](int index) {
       return Deref(*this, index);
   }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    MyArray<int> foo(3);
    foo[1] = 42;
    std::cout << "Value is " << foo[1] << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Simple `const`-ness cannot be used because you may need to read from a non-const instance, that is the reason for which you must delay the operation: the assignment happens "after" the access and the compiler doesn't tell you if the access will be later used as a target for assignment or not.

The idea is therefore that on access you just store away the index that has been requested and wait to know if a reading or a writing operation is happening. By providing an implicit conversion operator from the proxy to `T` you know when a reading operation occurs, by providing an assignment operator to the proxy from `T` you know when writing occurs.

Answer (score 4):

The `const` version means that if the object on which it is called is `const`, you are allowed to call that version of the `[]` operator, and only that version.

But if the object is not `const`, then both versions of the `[]` operator can be called, but the compiler will select the non-const version. In other words, for a non-const object, the non-const version of the operator can act as either the "setter" or "getter". This is why the same version is called in both cases in your example, because your `data` object is not const.

You would have to do something like this:

```
const Data& data_cref = data;
cout << data_cref[5];  // calls the const version of operator[]

Data& data_ref = data;
data_ref[5] = 1;       // calls the non-const version of operator[]
```

Answer (score 1):

To be compatible with the ordinary meaning of subscript, the subscript operator usually returns a reference to the element that is fetched. **By returning a reference, subscript can be used on either side of an assignment.**

Consequently, it is also usually a good idea to define both const and nonconst versions of this operator. When applied to a object, subscript should return a reference to const so that it is assign to the returned object.

----C++ Primer, Fifth Edition

Answer (score 0):

`const` version of your `operator[]` will be called for `const` data object:

```
const Data data;
cout << data[5];
```