# C++ bracket operator get/set

Tags: c++, c++11

I am puzzled with the following piece of code where I am trying to understand the difference between getter/setter of the C++ bracket operator.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T, std::size_t N>
class Buffer
{
public:
    Buffer() : _pos(0) {}
    ~Buffer() {}
    //T& operator[](std::size_t pos) { cout << "\nSet\n"; return _data[pos]; }
    const T& operator[](std::size_t pos) const { cout << "\nGet\n"; return _data[pos]; }    
private:
    T _data[N];
    std::size_t _pos;
};

int main()
{
    Buffer<int, 10> b;
    int i = b[0];
    (void)i;
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling it using GCC 4.9.3 (MinGW).
When I run it, it prints "Get" as expected, since I am not changing the Buffer object in the assignment

```
int i = b[0];
```

But if I un-comment the setter operator

```
T& operator[](std::size_t pos)
```

then this time the program prints "Set". I cannot explain this behavior.

I have read many examples, including [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19217813/operator-c-get-set), where it is recommended to use a 'proxy' class, but then I do not understand why this approach is not used in the implementation of std::array like in the [GCC implementation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a00752_source.html). My Buffer class is intended to be similar to std::array.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, but read the answers to the duplicate carefully.

Comment: Hint: change `Buffer<int, 10> b;` to `const Buffer<int, 10> b;`. See any difference in your output?

Comment: `T& operator[](std::size_t pos)` isn't different from `const T& operator[](std::size_t pos)` for this case, but you escape compile error, because second one actually got const argument  `this`, by declaring it  `const T& operator[](std::size_t pos) const`. Latter one is valid to use when the object it used on is const as well, in other cases compiler will prefer  former.

Comment: <pre>T& operator[](std::size_t pos)</pre> **it is** different from <pre>const T& operator[](std::size_t pos) const</pre>. The former tells me that I can change the referenced value, the latter tells me that I can't do it. Please note the **const** attribute for the getter method.